# REST interface using nginx httpluamodule

Tags: rest, nginx, lua

I'm just getting started with nginx and the [HttpLuaModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLuaModule).  I've created a test configuration file to familiarize myself with how things work.

now I'm trying to write some logic to accept GET, POST and DELETE requests for a specific type of resource.

I would like to create a "location" entry that would match the following URI / accept the following curl calls:

```
curl -i -X GET http://localhost/widgets/widget?name=testname&loc=20000 -H "Accept:application/json"
```

This is what my current nginx.conf looks like:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  nsps2;
root    /var/www/;
index   index.html index.htm;
#charset koi8-r;

#access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;
#curl http://localhost/hello?name=johndoe
location /hello {
        default_type "text/plain";
        content_by_lua '
        local rquri = ngx.var.request_uri;
        ngx.say("the uri is ", rquri ,".")

        local name = ngx.var.arg_name or "Anonymous"
                ngx.say("Hello, ", name, "!")
                ';
}

location / {
    root   /var/www/;
    index  index.html index.htm;
}

#curl -i -X GET http://localhost/widgets/widget?name=testname&loc=20000 -H "Accept:application/json"
location /widgets/widget {
        root /var/www/widgets;          
        default_type "text/pain";
        content_by_lua '
        local arga,argb = ngx.arg[1], ngx.arg[2] ;
        ngx.say("the arga is ", arga ,".")
        ngx.say("the argb is ", argb, ".")
        ';
}
```

Using the last "location" entry, I'm trying to 
1.  prove that the system is getting the GET request
2.  prove that I understand how to access the parameters passed in with the GET request.

I'm getting an error right now that looks like this:

```
2015/02/24 20:18:19 [error] 2354#0: *1 lua entry thread aborted: runtime error: content_by_lua:2: API disabled in the context of content_by_lua*
stack traceback:
coroutine 0:
    [C]: in function '__index'
    content_by_lua:2: in function <content_by_lua:1>, client: 127.0.0.1, server: nsps2, request: "GET /widgets/widget?name=testname?loc=20000 HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
```

I'm not too sure about what this error means / is trying to tell me. 
Any tips would be appreciated.

Thank you.

**EDIT 1**

I think the problem was something syntactically wrong.  I was reading the manual and found an example to try.  I've changed the code to look like this:

```
    location /widgets/widget {
            default_type "text/pain";
            content_by_lua '
        local args = ngx.req.get_uri_args()
        for key, val in pairs(args) do
            if type(val) == "table" then
                ngx.say(key, ": ", table.concat(val, ", "))                    
            else
                ngx.say(key, ": ", val)
            end
        end
            ';
    }
```

Now when I call the app like this:

```
 mytestdevbox2:/var/www/nsps2# curl -i -X GET http://localhost/widgets/widget?name=testname&loc=20000 -H "Accept:application/json"
-ash: -H: not found
mytestdevbox2:/var/www/nsps2# HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.6.2
Date: Tue, 24 Feb 2015 21:32:44 GMT
Content-Type: text/pain
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive

name: testname

[1]+  Done                       curl -i -X GET http://localhost/widgets/widget?name=testname
```

After the system displays the "name: testname" stuff, it just sits there until I hit "enter".  After I do that, then it proceeds to display the [1](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLuaModule)+ stuff. 
I'm not too sure what it's doing.

**EDIT 2:**

Adding quotes to the curl call did fix the problem:

```
mytestdevbox2:/var/www/nsps2# curl -i -X GET 'http://localhost/widgets/widget?name=testname&loc=20000'
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.6.2
Date: Wed, 25 Feb 2015 12:59:29 GMT
Content-Type: text/pain
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive

loc: 20000
name: testname
mytestdevbox2:/var/www/nsps2#
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem described in `EDIT 1` doesn't have anything to do with your question about nginx and is caused by not quoting the parameters for curl when you execute the command:

```
curl -i -X GET http://localhost/widgets/widget?name=testname&loc=20000
```

This is executed as two commands separated by '&': `curl -i -X GET http://localhost/widgets/widget?name=testname` and `loc=20000`; that's why you see the output after you already got the prompt back as the first command is now executed in the background. "1+ Done" message is a confirmation that the background process is terminated; it's just shown after you press Enter.

Wrap the URL with the query string in quotes and you should see the expected behavior.

Comment: Wow!  That worked!  Please see Edit 2 for details. I wouldn't have thought of that ... Just for future reference, should I have been reading the curl man pages... or what do you think should have tipped me off?

Comment: Difficult to say ;); usually, any unexpected messages, like `-ash: -H: not found`, give you a reason to check carefully what may be going on...
You can also use ';' as a separator instead of '&' as [W3C recommends](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/appendix/notes.html#h-B.2.2).

Comment: just fyi.  nginx doesn't seem to parse the parms properly when i separate using ";" in the URI.  Thanks though.  Good to know for future